# Any connection between schult ("debt") and Schule ("school")?

Tags: etymology

I am trying to understand the etymology of the German surname "**Schulz**".

According to Wiktionary the etymology of **Schulz** is:

> [Etymology:](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Schulz)
>
> Contraction of the Middle High German equivalent of Schultheiß
>   (“village headman, sheriff”), from schult (“debt”) + heizen (“to
>   order”).
>
> [Herkunft:](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Schulz)
>
> Kontraktion aus Schultheiß, dem Posten des Vorstehers eines Dorfes,
>   der die Abgaben für den Grundherrn einforderte.

In the dictionary of modern German I could not find these two words (schult, heizen) in these meanings... so maybe they are not used in these meanings anymore.

Is there any remote connection between modern German **Schule** ("school") and  Middle High German **schult** (“debt”)?

I have also noticed that in [Middle Dutch](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/schulen#Middle_Dutch), **schulen** means to take shelter. Any connection?

It is interesting to note that in the US, attending school often requires amassing stupid amounts of debt...

Comment: *Schuld*,  *Schultheiß* and *Schule* are way older than the American schooling system - It's unlikely there is a connection ;)

Comment: @tofro But universal free education is also a rather modern invention...

Comment: You might, by the way, look up *heißen* (jmd etwas zu tun heißen) in a modern dictionary - That's your "heizen" .

Comment: It is imanigable that the *Dorf-Schulze* as one of the learned authorities taught children, a job that has in living memory been covered by church personal often enough, but Germanic people were for the most part not christened. That "school" should derive from a word about "leisure time" is too ironic for my taste.

Comment: or as my neighbour says: „Die Schule ist an allem Schuld ...“???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Schule* derives (just like the English "school") from the Latin "schola".

*Schuld* or the compound *Schultheiß* you mention derives according to Grimm from Germanic *skulan*, which is also a common ancestor of *sollen* in German as well as *shall* in English.

Thus those two words are not likely to have a common ancestor.

With regards to the verb *schulen*, there are actually two manifestations of this verb in German:

*schulen* - being educated in school (common usage today) or, more generally, made fit for life (this also applies to, for example, trees in a *Baumschule* but not whales in a *Schule von Walen*, which is yet another word). This verb is by far the most common of the two and also derives from the Latin *schola*.

*schulen* - to look hideously (catch a glimpse, hide your view), also to squint. Regional to northern Germany and probably the same as the middle Dutch verb you mention. Not used commonly and has nothing to do with *Schule* or *Schuld*. The common German verb for "to squint" is *schielen* with the same ancestry.

Comment: `schulen - to look hideously` - I am not sure I understand what you mean, there is more than one way to interpret it... could you please paraphrase it? How is it related to "to be hidden/take shelter"?

Comment: A *[school](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/school)* of fish is "from Proto-Germanic *skulō (“crowd”), from Proto-Indo-European *(s)kʷel- (“crowd, people”)" but the learning "school" is "from Proto-Germanic *skōla (“school”), from Late Latin schola, scola (“learned discussion or dissertation, lecture, school”), from Ancient Greek σχολεῖον (skholeîon), from σχολή (skholḗ, “spare time, leisure; conversations and the knowledge gained through them during free time; the places where these conversations took place”), from Proto-Indo-European *seǵʰ- (“to hold, have, possess”). Influenced by [1] ..."

Comment: Of course saying "Late Latin" preceding Proto Germanic is a bit misleading.

Comment: There is no reason to ascribe this word to proto-Germanic. This is wiki-rubbish.